# How to dequeue or deregister all jquery scripts in wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, admin

I am working on a plugin and in plugin i am using `wordpress color picker`

color_picker.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('.cp-field').wpColorPicker();
});
```

and in index.php file:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'enqueue_color_picker');
function enqueue_color_picker($hook_suffix) {
    // first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
    wp_enqueue_style('wp-color-picker');
    wp_enqueue_script('cp-script-handle', plugin url.'js/color_picker.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true);
}
```

after that i refresh my admin page and view source it all jquery and jquery-ui scripts load before body tag end like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://site_url/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-p&amp;load%5B%5D=unch,iris,wp-color-picker,jquery-ui-sortable,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check&amp;ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://site_url/wp-content/plugins/wp_foo/js/color_picker.js?ver=4.0'></script>

<div class="clear"></div></div><!-- wpwrap -->
<script type="text/javascript">if(typeof wpOnload=='function')wpOnload();</script>
</body>
```

and when i comment color picker function all scripts go.

I want to unload or dequeue or deregister all unwanted scripts. I also try to dequeue or derigster scripts but nothing happen

```
add_action('admin_init', 'unload_all_jquery');
function unload_all_jquery() {
    //wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
    $jquery_ui = array(
        "jquery-ui-widget",
        "jquery-ui-mouse",
        "jquery-ui-accordion",
        "jquery-ui-autocomplete",
        "jquery-ui-slider",
        "jquery-ui-tabs",   
        "jquery-ui-draggable",
        "jquery-ui-droppable",
        "jquery-ui-selectable",
        "jquery-ui-position",
        "jquery-ui-datepicker",
        "jquery-ui-resizable",
        "jquery-ui-dialog",
        "jquery-ui-button"
    );

    foreach($jquery_ui as $script){
        wp_dequeue_script($script);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how can i do this.

Comment: Those scripts are "registered". You'll want to use [wp_deregister_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) instead. You should also be hooking into the `'admin_enqueue_scripts'` hook; not `admin_init`.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to "deregister" a script in the admin, you'll want to hook into the `'admin_enqueue_scripts'` hook. This is the hook that is also used to enqueue admin scripts (as the name implies).

In addition, you'll need to use [wp_deregister_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/) instead of `wp_dequeue_script()`. The reason for this is that the script has been "registered" to the queue, but not actually "enqueued." So, your final script will look something like:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'unload_all_jquery');
function unload_all_jquery() {
    //wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
    $jquery_ui = array(
        "jquery-ui-widget",
        "jquery-ui-mouse",
        "jquery-ui-accordion",
        "jquery-ui-autocomplete",
        "jquery-ui-slider",
        "jquery-ui-tabs",   
        "jquery-ui-draggable",
        "jquery-ui-droppable",
        "jquery-ui-selectable",
        "jquery-ui-position",
        "jquery-ui-datepicker",
        "jquery-ui-resizable",
        "jquery-ui-dialog",
        "jquery-ui-button"
    );

    foreach($jquery_ui as $script){
        wp_deregister_script($script);
    }
}
```